# WAMP "connection refused" HTTP 301 wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, apache, http, wamp, wampserver

I am using a wampserver on localhost to work on websites that I am hosting for test pourposes etc.. Usually when I copy a wordpress site to my development pc all I have to do is copy the files to my computer, import the database and make a few small changes to the local databse and presto - it works locally.

With one particular site I am having big problems however. I have been able to figure out a part of the problem, but I have no idea on how to solve it.

When I move the site to local I "connection refused" errormessage. The logs dont show any special action except for a:  (in the access.log - nothing in apache_error.log)

```
"GET /site.com HTTP/1.1" 301 241
```

the HTTP 301 message is a "Moved Permanently" message - for the life of my I cannot figure out where it is coming from however. The wordpress setting is normal, I do not have any special header referrers in my code...

Any ideas where the 301 "moved permanently" could be coming from are appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Look at .htaccess file in the root folder of this site.

Comment: already thought of that but the site doesnt have a .htaccess file

Comment: Is it possible that the site does use permalinks on its hosting, but you did not copy .htaccess because it was hidden?

Comment: The site has the default permalinks option selected in wordpress. There is no .htaccess however. I also have the "sticky links" addon from wpml activated... could the permalink settings be anywhere else then in the .htaccess?

Comment: AFAIK, if default permalinks is on, there should be mod_rewrite's directives somewhere: in the .htaccess of the site by default, but it can be placed in some level above, or even in the web-server .conf file. You can try to disable permalinks in the site on your PC and look if the error vanishes - just to make sure it's about premalinks and rewrites.

Comment: deactivating mod_rewrite on my pc didn't help :(
the strange thing is that i have quite a few worpress sites (which use the mod_rewrite) and with none of them I have this problem...

Comment: I've narrowed it down to the sitepress (WPML) module. If I deactivate it on the local machine the error dissapears. I'm not quite sure why it was causing it, but there is a new version out so I'll update and hope for the best.
Thanks for helping!